# Merging two linked list into new one java

Tags: java, exception, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to merge two sorted Linked List into new Linked-List.

like `l1`: `1->3->7` and `l2`: `0->2->10` then `l3` must be : `0->1->2->3->7->10`.

But it is giving run time error:

```
void Merge(node Head1,node Head2){

    while(Head2!=null || Head1!=null){
        node temp=new node();
        int Head1info=Head1.getInfo();
        int Head2info=Head2.getInfo();

        if(Head1info < Head2info){
            temp.setInfo(Head2.getInfo());
            Head2=Head2.getLink();
        } else{
            temp.setInfo(Head1.getInfo());
            Head1=Head1.getLink();
        }

        if(Tail==null){
            Head=Tail=temp;
        }
        else{
            Tail.setLink(temp);
            Tail=temp;
        }
    }

    if(Head1==null){ 
        while(Head2!=null){
            node temp=new node();
            temp.setInfo(Head2.getInfo());
            Head2=Head2.getLink(); 
            Tail.setLink(temp);
            Tail=temp;
        }
    }

    if(Head2==null){ 
        while(Head1!=null){
            node temp=new node();
            temp.setInfo(Head1.getInfo());
            Head1=Head1.getLink(); 
            Tail.setLink(temp);
            Tail=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(Head2!=null || Head1!=null)` -> `while(Head2!=null && Head1!=null)`.

Comment: Always include your errors with your post please.

Answer (score 1):

The error should be because of this code

```
while(Head2!=null || Head1!=null){
```

since you are doing

```
Head1.getInfo() and Head2.getInfo();
```

So change it to

```
while(Head2!=null && Head1!=null){
```

If one of them(`head1` or `head2` but not both) becomes `NULL`, you will get [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) during runtime.

Comment: Solved !! :) Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go for this simple way that works in O(n*log(n)):

```
List<T> result= new ArrayList<T>();
result.addAll(list1);
result.addAll(list2);
Collections.sort(result);
```

Combining with `Stream` is slighty better.

```
Stream resultStream = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).sorted();
List<String> result = resultStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have tested the second way with two lists each with over `10,000,000` items sorted. It took roughly `476 milliseconds` to perform merging.

If your lists don't cointain really big data (more than millions), the performance really doesn't matter.

Comment: The OP asks why his own custom merge function in a custom linked list implementation doesn't work, and your post gives a completely different implementation of the function that doesnt use the OP's linked list. That looks more like a comment to me - not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am trying to implement data structure in java from scratch.